# Differentiation. Rate of increase

Tags: calculus, related-rates

The radius of a sphere is increasing at a rate of $4 cms^{-1}.$ 
Find the rate of increase of the surface area when the radius is $5cm.$

Surface area $= 4\pi r^2$

Comment: What part do you find undoable?

Comment: Where did you get this question? Are you familiar with derivatives?

Comment: Do not remove the content of your question after getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is given that $\frac{dr}{dt}=4$ cm/s.

As you said, $A=4\pi r^2$. Now differentiate this w.r.t. time to get

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=4 \pi \cdot 2r \frac{dr}{dt}$$
When $r=5$ cm, this will be equal to

$$8 \pi \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 160\pi\ {cm}^2/s.$$

Comment: What was the downvote for?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I know why.  A lot of people on this site don't like questions where the OPs didn't put enough effort.  Instead of just punishing the OPs with downvotes, they also punished people who answer the questions as well.  I don't agree with this practice.

Answer (score 0):

If $r$ is the radius of the sphere, then given that $dr/dt=4.$ Now if $S= 4\pi r^2$ then rate of increase of the surface area  when the radius $r=5$ is given by $dS/dt=4\pi 2.r.dr/dt=4.\pi.2.5.4=160\pi$  sq.cm/sec.